# Find out whether linearity for the functions $f$ and $g$ persists

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given $$f: \mathbb{C}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2, \begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
ia+b\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,g: 
\mathbb{C}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2, \begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
ia+b\\ 
c+1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I like to find out if linearity exists for each function? If I understood correctly, it needs to be shown that they are homogenous and additive. So let 
$$\vec{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\ 
b_1\\ 
c_1
\end{bmatrix} \,\,\,\,, 
\vec{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_2\\ 
b_2\\ 
c_2
\end{bmatrix} \,\,\,\, \text{ where each is from } \,\, \mathbb{C^3}$$

Because the functions need to be homogenous and additive, we need to do

$$f(\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2}) = f(\begin{bmatrix}
a_1+a_2\\ 
b_1+b_2\\ 
c_1+c_2
\end{bmatrix}) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
i(a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2)\\ 
(c_1+c_2) 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
(ia_1+b_1)+(ia_2+b_2)\\ 
(c_1+c_2) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

But from here I don't know how to continue and what to do ? :C

Comment: The next step in proving homogeneity is to calculate $f(\vec{v_1})$ and $f(\vec{v_2})$, then add the results. If this is the same as $f(\vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2})$ as you have correctly calculated, then you have additivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show $f(v_1 + v_2) = f(v_1) + f(v_2)$. If we compute the values $f(v_1)$ and $f(v_2)$ we find that
$$
\begin{align*}
f(v_1) + f(v_2) 
 &= \begin{bmatrix}
ia_1 + b_1 \\
c_1
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
ia_2+b_2\\ 
c_2 
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
(ia_1+b_1)+(ia_2+b_2)\\ 
c_1+c_2 
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= f(v_1 + v_2).
\end{align*}
$$
Thus, we see that $f$ is linear (if we quickly compute $f(av) = af(v)$).
Another way to see this quickly is to note that all the components of $f(v)$ are linear combinations of the entries of $v$.
This is not the case for $g$ due to the addition of 1 in the second component, hence $g$ is not linear.
Alternatively, one can plug in $0$ to get
$$g(0) = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1 
\end{bmatrix} \ne 0.$$

Comment: This proves $f$ is additive. We'd need a proof of homogeneity, i.e. $f(cv) = cf(v)$ for all scalars $c$ and vectors $v$, in order to be linear. Unfortunately, proving $f(0) = 0$ doesn't cut it!

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up what I wanted to write. Should be fixed now; I think OP can do the computation on their own now that they have an example of how it works :)

Comment: Many thanks and also for the comment this is very helpful already! x)